# Exporting Calendar and Sending Mail Outlook PHP

Tags: php, email, outlook, calendar, smtp

I get an Error: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp64\www\stage\views\mailtest.php on line 125

I didn't know how to modified the port.
I had another code for sending and recieve mails and it's worked but now i need to create an event Calendar with sending mail.

```
function sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location)
{
    $domain = 'hotmail.com';

    //Create Email Headers
    $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());

    $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
    $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

    //Create Email Body (HTML)
    $message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= "<html>\n";
    $message .= "<body>\n";
    $message .= '<p>Dear '.$to_name.',</p>';
    $message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    $message .= "</body>\n";
    $message .= "</html>\n";
    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

    $ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
        'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
        'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
        'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
        'TZID:Eastern Time' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
        'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
        'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
        'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
        'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
        'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
        'DTEND;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
        'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
        'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
        'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
        'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
        'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
        'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
        'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
        'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
        'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST'."\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $ical;

    $mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

    return ($mailsent)?(true):(false);
}
$from_name = "Omar Krichene";
$from_address = "krichene30@hotmail.com";
$to_name = "Omar Krichene";
$to_address = "krichen30@gmail.com";
$startTime = "11/07/2018 18:00:00";
$endTime = "11/07/2018 19:00:00";
$subject = "My Test Subject";
$description = "My Awesome Description";
$location = "Krichene House";
sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location);
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is not able to connect to the SMTP server.
Have you checked if an SMTP server is running on the localhost or the computer the script is running from at port 25?
If not you'll need to provide a working SMTP server address and login to it.

Comment: how can i checked it ? (i send an email like this and it's worked, i don't think that is about that)

Comment: Try telnetting: telnet localhost 25 . If that command yields a negative result, something in your system or the script configuration has changed